# How to make text always be at the bottom of the page with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form built with pure HTML and CSS and I am trying to achieve is that this `version text` is at the bottom of the page. See image below what I want to achieve.

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>Login form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f9fbff
        }

        .source-image {
            width: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: auto;
            position: fixed;
            max-width: 100%;
            display: block
        }

        #login-form {
            width: 460px;
            background: 0 0;

            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            margin: 20px 0
        }

        .input_img {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 20px;
            left: 13px;
            height: 30px
        }

        #login-form h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 60px;
            color: #191c3c;
            font-size: 30px
        }

        .logoHolder>img {
            width: 60%;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: block
        }

        #login-form p {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #333
        }

        #login-form p a {
            color: #191c3c;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #login-form p {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #333
        }

        #login-form .entryText {

            font-size: 18px
        }

        #login-form p a:focus {
            border: 1px solid #515772
        }

        #login-form label {
            color: #4a4d67;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-bottom: 10px !important
        }

        .input-box {
            position: relative;
            margin: 30px 0
        }

        .input-box input {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #333;
            border: 1px solid #51577245;
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 1.2;
            font-size: 18px;
            outline: 0;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0 5px;
            height: 72px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding-left: 57px;
            box-shadow: 0 3px 11px 0 rgba(81, 87, 114, .2);
            margin-top: 15px
        }

        .input-box input:focus {
            border: 1px solid #515772
        }

        .input-box span::before {
            content: attr(data-placeholder);
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 5px;
            color: #515772;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            z-index: -1;
            transition: .5s;
            padding-left: 20px
        }

        .validation {

            border-color: #c00000 !important;
            margin-bottom: 7px;

        }

        .feedback {

            color: #c00000;
        }

        ::placeholder {
            margin-left: 60px;
            color: #8b8d9d;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        .cursor {
            width: 17px
        }

        .input-box span::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 2px;
            background: linear-gradient(120deg, #2196F3, #FF5722);
            transition: .5s
        }

        .focus+span::before {
            top: -5px
        }

        .focus+span::after {
            width: 100%
        }

        .login-btn {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 62px;
            border: none;
            background: #515772;
            background-size: 200%;
            color: #fff;
            outline: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 20px 0 0;
            border-radius: 8px;
            transition: .5s;
            font-size: 18px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-weight: 700
        }

        .login-btn:focus {
            border: 2px solid #000
        }

        .login-btn:hover {
            background-color: #2d3142
        }

        .bottom-links {
            margin-top: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 13px
        }

        .bottom-links>p>a {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .bottom-links>p {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        @media (max-width:768px) {
            #login-form {

                top: 40%;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .source-image {
                display: none
            }
        }

        @media (max-width:1440px) {
            .source-image {
                display: none
            }
        }

        .version {
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .conta {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <main>
        <div class="conta">
            <form action="" id="login-form">
                <div class="logoHolder">
                </div>
                <div class="input-box"><label for="username">Username</label><input id="username" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="input-box"><label for="password">Password</label><input id="password" name="password"
                        type="password" placeholder=""></div><button type="submit" class="login-btn"
                    aria-label="Prijava gumb">Enter</button>
                <div class="bottom-links">
                    <small class="version">v3.0.</small>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

What I trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Can anybody help me with this, what will be the best way to achieve this? Can any good soul try to help me with this?

Comment: This tutorial will give you details about fixed footer block https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a **responsive solution**, that allows you to resize the window without having particular troubles, like this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>Login form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f9fbff;
        }

        .source-image {
            width: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: auto;
            position: fixed;
            max-width: 100%;
            display: block
        }

        #login-form {
            width: 460px;
            background: 0 0;

            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            margin: 20px 0
        }

        .input_img {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 20px;
            left: 13px;
            height: 30px
        }

        #login-form h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 60px;
            color: #191c3c;
            font-size: 30px
        }

        .logoHolder>img {
            width: 60%;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: block
        }

        #login-form p {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #333
        }

        #login-form p a {
            color: #191c3c;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #login-form p {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #333
        }

        #login-form .entryText {

            font-size: 18px
        }

        #login-form p a:focus {
            border: 1px solid #515772
        }

        #login-form label {
            color: #4a4d67;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-bottom: 10px !important
        }

        .input-box {
            position: relative;
            margin: 30px 0
        }

        .input-box input {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #333;
            border: 1px solid #51577245;
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 1.2;
            font-size: 18px;
            outline: 0;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0 5px;
            height: 72px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding-left: 57px;
            box-shadow: 0 3px 11px 0 rgba(81, 87, 114, .2);
            margin-top: 15px
        }

        .input-box input:focus {
            border: 1px solid #515772
        }

        .input-box span::before {
            content: attr(data-placeholder);
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 5px;
            color: #515772;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            z-index: -1;
            transition: .5s;
            padding-left: 20px
        }

        .validation {

            border-color: #c00000 !important;
            margin-bottom: 7px;

        }

        .feedback {

            color: #c00000;
        }

        ::placeholder {
            margin-left: 60px;
            color: #8b8d9d;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        .cursor {
            width: 17px
        }

        .input-box span::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 2px;
            background: linear-gradient(120deg, #2196F3, #FF5722);
            transition: .5s
        }

        .focus+span::before {
            top: -5px
        }

        .focus+span::after {
            width: 100%
        }

        .login-btn {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 62px;
            border: none;
            background: #515772;
            background-size: 200%;
            color: #fff;
            outline: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 20px 0 0;
            border-radius: 8px;
            transition: .5s;
            font-size: 18px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-weight: 700
        }

        .login-btn:focus {
            border: 2px solid #000
        }

        .login-btn:hover {
            background-color: #2d3142
        }

        .bottom-links {
            background: transparent;
            position: fixed;
            inline-size: -webkit-fill-available;
            bottom: 10px;
            z-index: 10;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 13px
        }

        .bottom-links>p>a {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .bottom-links>p {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        @media (max-width:768px) {
            #login-form {

                top: 40%;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .source-image {
                display: none
            }
        }

        @media (max-width:1440px) {
            .source-image {
                display: none
            }
        }

        .version {
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .conta {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <main>
        <div class="conta">
            <form action="" id="login-form">
                <div class="logoHolder">
                </div>
                <div class="input-box"><label for="username">Username</label><input id="username" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="input-box"><label for="password">Password</label><input id="password" name="password"
                        type="password" placeholder=""></div><button type="submit" class="login-btn"
                    aria-label="Prijava gumb">Enter</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
    </main>
    <div class="bottom-links">
        <small class="version">v3.0.</small>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I just put the `.bottom-links` div outside the `main` tag, than I set these properties (for `.bottom-links`):

- `background: transparent` to make that without a background, in order to avoid issues with the elements behind;
- `position: fixed` to make the element stuck on the screen;
- `bottom: 10px`; to make the element above the end of the page by 10 pixels;
- `z-index: 10` to make the element in prominence from the others.

**EDIT**
I also inserted:

- `inline-size: -webkit-fill-available` to center the `.bottom-links` elements

Comment: If you add a message saying what you have changed and why it is easier for the OP to implement it and learn from it

Comment: Explanation added

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: **Edit:** Now `.bottom-links` aligns items at the center horizontally

Answer (score 1):

Try the attached code, it will surely work and if you face any issue let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

I have made some changes  in `.bottom-links` and decreased some CSS.

I have a suggestion for you that next time you code use **Viewport Units** like **vw** and **vh** instead of **px** and **%** because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

```css
 html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            box-sizing: border-box
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f9fbff
        }

        .source-image {
            width: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: auto;
            position: fixed;
            max-width: 100%;
            display: block
        }

        #login-form {
            width: 460px;
            background: 0 0;

            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            margin: 20px 0
        }

        .input_img {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 20px;
            left: 13px;
            height: 30px
        }

        #login-form h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 60px;
            color: #191c3c;
            font-size: 30px
        }

        .logoHolder>img {
            width: 60%;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: block
        }

        #login-form p {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #333
        }

        #login-form p a {
            color: #191c3c;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #login-form p {
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #333
        }

        #login-form .entryText {

            font-size: 18px
        }

        #login-form p a:focus {
            border: 1px solid #515772
        }

        #login-form label {
            color: #4a4d67;
            font-weight: 700;
            margin-bottom: 10px !important
        }

        .input-box {
            position: relative;
            margin: 30px 0
        }

        .input-box input {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #333;
            border: 1px solid #51577245;
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 1.2;
            font-size: 18px;
            outline: 0;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 0 5px;
            height: 72px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding-left: 57px;
            box-shadow: 0 3px 11px 0 rgba(81, 87, 114, .2);
            margin-top: 15px
        }

        .input-box input:focus {
            border: 1px solid #515772
        }

        .input-box span::before {
            content: attr(data-placeholder);
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 5px;
            color: #515772;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            z-index: -1;
            transition: .5s;
            padding-left: 20px
        }

        .validation {

            border-color: #c00000 !important;
            margin-bottom: 7px;

        }

        .feedback {

            color: #c00000;
        }

        ::placeholder {
            margin-left: 60px;
            color: #8b8d9d;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 700;
        }

        .cursor {
            width: 17px
        }

        .input-box span::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 2px;
            background: linear-gradient(120deg, #2196F3, #FF5722);
            transition: .5s
        }

        .focus+span::before {
            top: -5px
        }

        .focus+span::after {
            width: 100%
        }

        .login-btn {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 62px;
            border: none;
            background: #515772;
            background-size: 200%;
            color: #fff;
            outline: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 20px 0 0;
            border-radius: 8px;
            transition: .5s;
            font-size: 18px;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-weight: 700
        }

        .login-btn:focus {
            border: 2px solid #000
        }

        .login-btn:hover {
            background-color: #2d3142
        }

        .bottom-links {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 13px;
            margin-top: 46.5vw;
        }

        @media (max-width:768px) {
            #login-form {

                top: 40%;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .source-image {
                display: none
            }
        }

        @media (max-width:1440px) {
            .source-image {
                display: none
            }
        }

        .version {
            font-size: 14px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        .conta {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>Login form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <main>
        <div class="conta">
            <form action="" id="login-form">
                <div class="logoHolder">
                </div>
                <div class="input-box"><label for="username">Username</label><input id="username" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="input-box"><label for="password">Password</label><input id="password" name="password"
                        type="password" placeholder=""></div><button type="submit" class="login-btn"
                    aria-label="Prijava gumb">Enter</button>
            </form>
        </div>
<div class="bottom-links">
                    <small class="version">v3.0.</small>
                </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you add a message saying what you have changed and why it is easier for the OP to implement it and learn from it

Comment: @NicoShultz thank you, now when I resize the browser this version text moves at the top, you can try this

Comment: @nukleus this is not my answer :)

Comment: @nukleus, if you want a responsive solution (where also resize does not affect the page with front-end issues), you can check mine

Comment: @IvanNukleus Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the `.bottom-links` element outside the form and into the main wrapper and gave it the following css to position it at the bottom (20px from the bottom edge) and center the text

```
.bottom-links {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background-color: #f9fbff
}

.source-image {
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block
}

#login-form {
  width: 460px;
  background: 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 20px 0
}

.input_img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 13px;
  height: 30px
}

#login-form h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  color: #191c3c;
  font-size: 30px
}

.logoHolder>img {
  width: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block
}

#login-form p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333
}

#login-form p a {
  color: #191c3c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#login-form p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333
}

#login-form .entryText {
  font-size: 18px
}

#login-form p a:focus {
  border: 1px solid #515772
}

#login-form label {
  color: #4a4d67;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important
}

.input-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0
}

.input-box input {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #51577245;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 57px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 11px 0 rgba(81, 87, 114, .2);
  margin-top: 15px
}

.input-box input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #515772
}

.input-box span::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  color: #515772;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .5s;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.validation {
  border-color: #c00000 !important;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.feedback {
  color: #c00000;
}

 ::placeholder {
  margin-left: 60px;
  color: #8b8d9d;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.cursor {
  width: 17px
}

.input-box span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, #2196F3, #FF5722);
  transition: .5s
}

.focus+span::before {
  top: -5px
}

.focus+span::after {
  width: 100%
}

.login-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 62px;
  border: none;
  background: #515772;
  background-size: 200%;
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: .5s;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 700
}

.login-btn:focus {
  border: 2px solid #000
}

.login-btn:hover {
  background-color: #2d3142
}

.bottom-links {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px
}

.bottom-links>p>a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.bottom-links>p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  #login-form {
    top: 40%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .source-image {
    display: none
  }
}

@media (max-width:1440px) {
  .source-image {
    display: none
  }
}

.version {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.conta {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom-links {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <main>
    <div class="conta">
      <form action="" id="login-form">
        <div class="logoHolder">
        </div>
        <div class="input-box"><label for="username">Username</label><input id="username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="input-box"><label for="password">Password</label><input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="">         </div>
        <button type="submit" class="login-btn" aria-label="Prijava gumb">Enter</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-links">
      <small class="version">v3.0.</small>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try bottom style after position style setting it to relative and then give bottom as you wish to, position is the best option to set any element on any position of webpage.